# Cron won't run Laravel scheduled jobs

Tags: php, linux, laravel, cron

I'm following Laravel's basic tutorial for scheduled jobs, using the Kernel.php file directly from the documentation.

My crontab file is:

```
* * * * * date >> CRONTRACK.txt
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/vagrant/Code/sample/artisan schedule:run >> /home/vagrant/Code/laravel_cron_output.txt
```

The cron is running. I get a new datetime entry in CRONTRACK.txt every minute.
Running this command in terminal works as well:

```
/usr/bin/php /home/vagrant/Code/sample/artisan schedule:run >> /home/vagrant/Code/laravel_cron_output.txt
```

Has anyone had similar issues using cron jobs to run Laravel's scheduled jobs?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

for setting up the job scheduling you can create custom commands for each task using `kernel.php` an example shows below for sending sms from queue table.

In the kernel file add the command in to the array.

```
protected $commands = [
        \App\Console\Commands\Inspire::class,
        \App\Console\Commands\SmsProcess::class,
    ];
```

Create a class `SmsProcess` in commands look like .

```
class SmsProcess extends Command {
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'smsprocess';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Process the sms queue';

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle() {
     //you cron job code here
    }
}
```

then in `Kernel.php` file set your preferred time like below , inside `schedule()`

```
$schedule->command('smsprocess')
            ->everyMinute()
            ->sendOutputTo('storage/logs/smsprocess.log');
```

Now simply set the cronjob in your contab file of server like below.

```
* *  * * *   user   php /var/www/html/projectfolder/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jobin for your reply.
I found that the bug is on the cron layer. By making the crontab file in windows i added carriage returns which linux refused to interpret correctly. 
Remaking the crontab file in a notepad++ or sublime text resolved the issue.